# ActionBarActivity throwing confiqure built path error

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-actionbaractivity

I am trying to built action bar in my app. I have appcompact v7 as a library project and i have referenced it to my project as well. I have spent a whole day but still not get the solution!!

Here is my Java built path window
[image]
Here is my Project's imported libraries
[image]
And This is the error that i am getting[image]

Plz help if any one can. Anticipatory thanks

Answer (score 0):

You also have to Add   **android-support-v7-appcompat.jar**  to your project lib folder.

You can find .jar in your android sdk folder:    **android sdk\extras\android\compatibility\v7\appcompat\libs**

copy it from above path and paste it inside project lib folder.

Comment: thanks for Quick reply. i just did it but still getting the same error. any other solution?